# Autohotkey send formatted datetime

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to send the datetime that is selected in this GUI, but I need to format it a specific way. For testing I am sending the output to notepad "Untitled"

```
Gui, Add, Text,, Summary
Gui, Add, Edit, vEdit
Gui, Add, Text,, Date of Change
Gui, Add, DateTime, vdatetime,
Gui, Add, Button,, OK
Gui, Show, x403 y262 h310 w392, New GUI Window
Return


ButtonOK:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

WinActivate Untitled

Send %Edit%{Enter}
Send, %datetime%,{Enter}

ExitApp

GuiClose:
ExitApp

Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

Currently the output is:

```
test Summary
20150811161206,
```

I need it to be in this format:

```
test Summary
8/11/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [FormatTime](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm)

```
FormatTime, TimeString, %datetime%, MM/d/yy hh:mm:ss tt
```